# Getting class name from Exception type object

Tags: python, exception

Consider this method, I need, `ValueError` to be printed, instead `type` is printed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
import traceback

def test():
    try:
        raise ValueError('Test')
    except:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print(exc_type.__class__.__name__)


test()
```

Comment: never use a bare-except, use `except SomeError as e: print(type(e))`... or in this case, just `print(exc_type)` or `print(exc_type.__name__)` the type of any `__class__` is `type`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I was being dumb! Wasted some time on this, used, exc_type.__name__ and it works perfectly.

Comment: @justdan23 This may be off-topic, but even in this case I would still recommend to use `except BaseException as e:` over `except:`, both because it is more convenient to log any errors if you don't have to call `sys.exc_info()` and because it is more explicit, and signals to the reader that indeed the author of the code does want to catch _every_ possible exception, including ones like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` -- and not because they don't understand the semantics of Python exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved it:

```
except Exception as error:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_context = sys.exc_info()

    sExceptionName = str(exc_type.__name__)
    sExceptionReason = str(exc_value)
    sExceptionTraceback = str(traceback.format_exception(exc_context))

    rHttpResponse = JsonResponse( 
        {
            "status": "error",
            "exception": {
                "name": sExceptionName,
                "reason": sExceptionReason,
                "traceback": sExceptionTraceback 
            }
        }
    )

return rHttpResponse
```

The goal being where any Exception is serialized to the actual Exception in a recognizable form.

The end result is something a caller can determine how much to show to give the user some smart error message to capture and send to a help desk.

Comment: Printing it to the screen is a bad practice.  You should return the error details in JSON form so the caller can do something with it besides passing back a 500.

Comment: Also, all responses to any Web Service should be HTTP 200 even for errors.  Why?  Because the other error codes are not for you to use and many will strip any response data (especially a 500).